# CSS: page bottom decoration and body height

Tags: html, css

There is a layout with central block "page" that has left, right and bottom background decorations (the light green plants on green background).

Example [**page**](http://goo.gl/d2OxY7)

The problem is with the Bottom decoration, that is an empty bottom block, that is intended only to show its background image. 
In order to be visible it must have height defined, however this height extends whole body height, and the window always scrollable to the down of the Bottom decoration block

You can change the "page" block height to something high, like 1000px or more to see the problem.

I'd like that full height bottom decoration will be seen only on short pages, where there's a lot of space beneath the page  (like on initioal view). And on the long pages there should remain minimal gap of 20px height.

Shortly, it must only be visible on the remaining space, not extend the page by it's own height

I'm sure it is possible, but I'm stuck

Thanks

Comment: Why did you apply the background image to your `.sides` ?

Comment: In order that it will repeat-y to fill any page length

Comment: Yes but i mean why did you not apply the background to the body?

Comment: To be able to fit the "sides" background bottom position with "page" and "bottom" background. So that the images will be exactly connected together

Comment: Assuming you want a full page background, a white `div` over it that is padded (or actually 'margined') from the sides by a few pixels, otherwise covering 100% of the width, by default being as high as required by its contents, but with a height that can be set dynamically, then all you need is: a body with a background image defined, `html, body` set to `height:100%` in your CSS, a `div` as a wrapper with `height:100%` and `margin-bottom` set to `190px` and inside that a `div` that will function as your actual content area with its `margin` set to a specific amount of pixels from the sides.

Comment: Ps.: Beware of [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Not exactly: white div has fixed width  and dynamic height, margined "auto" to take center. 
I can't set bottom image to body

Comment: the sides image bottom should be exactly at the top of bottom image and it should be always connected to the point where the white block ends. If the white block height is small, body background will be stuck to bottom of the window and not to white block

Comment: In that case, just apply the background-image to the wrapper div and when changing the height of the main container, change the height of the wrapper instead, and apply 100% height to the content area.

Comment: Look... the javascripted height change control is just for easy demonstration of the problem. The page height is fully dependent on content amount. I have nothing to do with wrapper height, it just wraps the white bcontent lock.

Comment: Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/PgSU6/) what you are looking for?

Comment: No. What I want is: 1. "1000x1000" or any other painting will be always just beneath the content. 2. It will not add it's height to page height

Comment: illustration shows the problem: .
http://i.snag.gy/L29x5.jpg <- There must be no scroll in this case

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, simple fix

```
.wrapper {overflow: hidden;  min-width: 1000px; }
```

Here's the result:

```
http://62.90.136.69/resultbottomdecor.html
```

Thanks